# Fetched data from backend but unable to access it in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have used nodejs and xampp to create a server. From there, I fetched the data via React as frontend. The data is logging in the console but when I try to access the values, it's showing as cannot read property of undefined.

This is the result of the backend API

```
[{"id":1,"Featured":"true","Ratings":5}]
```

This is the code in the frontend

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function QueryData() {
  const [backenddata, setBackenddata] = useState([]);

  async function fetchData(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const result = await response.json()
    setBackenddata(result);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let url = "http://localhost:3001/";
    fetchData(url);
  }, []);

  console.log(backenddata[0]) // This is result {"id":1,"Featured":"true","Ratings":5}
  console.log(backenddata[0].id)  // Error -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
  console.log(backenddata[0].Featured)  // Error -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Featured' of undefined

  return <div>backenddata</div>;
}
```

I have tried useState() and also useState({}), but the same error kicked in. Please help me out to access the data from the source. Thanks

Comment: add check is `backenddata[0]` exist or not, then use it, as in the first case when data is not fetched yet, you will get undefined for `backenddata[0]`, and it's why you see these errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useEffect` runs after the initial render, so initially you will get following output for the `console.log` statements below the `useEffect`

```
console.log(backenddata[0])              // undefined
console.log(backenddata[0].id)           // Error
console.log(backenddata[0].Featured)     // Error
```

After the initial render, `useEffect` executes and the state is updated which leads to a re-render of your component. When the component re-renders, the `console.log` statements will output the data correctly BUT the problem is that an error is thrown during the initial render because you are trying to access the properties of an object which doesn't yet exists.

**Solution:**

- You could use [`Optional chaining (?.)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

  ```
  console.log(backenddata[0]?.id)           
  console.log(backenddata[0]?.Featured)
  ```
- Log the data inside the `fetchData` function

  ```
  export default function QueryData() {
      const [backenddata, setBackenddata] = useState([]);

      async function fetchData(url) {
         const response = await fetch(url);
         const result = await response.json();

         console.log(result[0]);
         console.log(result[0].id) ;
         console.log(result[0].Featured);

         setBackenddata(result);
      }

      useEffect(() => {
        let url = "http://localhost:3001/";
        fetchData(url);
      }, []);

      return <div>backenddata</div>;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks Yousaf, I kept as optional (console.log(backenddata[0]?.id)) and that worked charm.